# Handling deletion of Core Data objects in to-many relationships

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

Using Core Data, I'm looking to setup a tagging system with the following to-many relationship:

```
article.tags <<------->> tag.articles
```

In this scenario an `article` can have numerous `tags`, and those same `tags` can be assigned to multiple `articles`. Whenever an `article`'s tags are edited, I remove all previous `tags` associated with the `article` and re-add those that are still relevant, like so:

```
// Remove any existing tags from this article
if(article.tags.count)
{
    NSSet *existingEventTags = [article.tags copy];
    for (NSManagedObject *tag in existingEventTags)
    {
        [[article mutableSetValueForKey:@"tags"] removeObject:tag];
        [moc deleteObject:tag];
    }
}

// Now re-assign any applicable tags to this article
for(NSString *tag in tags)
{
    Tag *existingTag = [self existingTagWithString:tag];
    if(existingTag)
    {
        [article addTagsObject:existingTag];
    }
    else
    {
        NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tag" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
        Tag *newTag = (Tag *)[[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entityDescription insertIntoManagedObjectContext:moc];
        newTag.name = tag;
        [article addTagsObject:newTag];
    }
}
```

My question is how best to handle the delete rules associated with the two relationships. Essentially the behaviour I'm looking for is that when I remove a `tag` from an `article`, I only want to delete it entirely if no other `articles` have been tagged with it.

To accomplish this I've set my `tag.articles` relationship to Nullify, and my `articles.tags` relationship to Cascade. However when deleting an article any tags associated with it (regardless of whether they're associated with other articles) are removed. To test this I've written a simple debug function which I'll include below:

```
- (void)debugTags
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tag" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    // Execute the fetch.
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *objects = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (objects != nil && [objects count] > 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Found %d tags", [objects count]);
        for(Tag *tag in objects)
        {
            NSLog(@"\t%@ (%d events)", tag.name, tag.articles.count);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"No tags found!");
    }
}
```

For completeness, here's an example output (showing the creation of two `articles` with two shared `tags`: food and fastfood). Following the deletion of one `article`, I'd expect to still find food and fastfood in the store, but with a relationship count of 1.

```
Before deletion
---------------

Found 4 tags
   breakfast (1 events)
   food (2 events)
   fastfood (2 events)
   lunch (1 events)

After deletion
--------------

Found 1 tags
   lunch (1 events)
```

Comment: It looks fine to me. These rules are correct. Did you made any test to see if it works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution I found to this problem was to set both delete rules to Nullify, and to handle the deletion in my `article`'s `NSManagedObject` `prepareForDeletion` method:

```
- (void)prepareForDeletion
{
    [super prepareForDeletion];

    for (Tag *tag in self.tags)
    {
        if(tag.events.count == 1)
        {
            [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:tag];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice ! I didn't know this method. Thanks for sharing ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct except delete rules. With this configuration CoreData do not wont save context with error:

```
 NSValidationErrorKey=events, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1600.), NSValidationErrorValue=Relationship 'articles' on managed object
```

To accomplish this you should set tag.articles relationship to Nullify, and my articles.tags relationship to Cascade. This will work as expected.

And second. Your code crashed with exception: **Collection <_NSFaultingMutableSet: 0x841de10> was mutated while being enumerated.** Make a copy of relationships to safely enumerate through it:

```
    NSSet* tags = [[object valueForKey:@"tags"] copy];
    for (NSManagedObject *tag in tags) {
        [[object mutableSetValueForKey:@"tags"] removeObject:tag];
        [context deleteObject:tag];
    }
```

Comment: Good catch. The original post contained untested pseudo-code which I've since updated. Unfortunately the delete rules you've suggested aren't working as I'd expect them to. Again, I've updated the original question to better explain the issue.